# How to access $_FILES in magentos way?

Tags: magento-1, coding-standards, magento-ecg

For ECG you should avoid using "superglobals", but is there any Magento, Zend or Varien method to replace `$_FILES`? Couldn't find anything in `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http` or `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` or `Zend` docuomentation.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can used Object Manager and Media Storage Uploader of magento to get $_FILES data.I know using object manager is not a good idea.

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $fileSystem = $objectManager>create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
 $mediaPath=$fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('/catalog/product');   
 $uploader = $objectManager->create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',['fileId' => 'file']);    
 $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
 $imageAdapter = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
 $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
 $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
 $result = $uploader->save($mediaPath);
```

Comment: quesrtion is abount magento1 not magento2,Please check question.